# "File size unexpectedly exceeded ZIP64 limit" while saving excel workbook

Tags: python-3.x, excel, zip, pyexcelerate

I am trying to create an excel sheet with large data and save it to the disk.
I use pyexcelerate module as it is faster than others.
I also do some styling. So, converting to csv is not an option for me.
As the excel sheet is large, it is giving this ZIP64 file limit error internally from pyexcelerate.
What I learned is that, the size limit is 2GB.
However, What I predict is that the file size shouldn't come more than 500MB in my case.
So, wondering why I am getting this error.

Is there any work around to overcome this limitation ?

A sample code is here..

```
import pandas as pd
import pyexcelerate

dfM=pd.read_csv('largefile.csv')
df_format=pd.read_csv('format.csv')

# Remove dup columns from dataframe if any.
dfM=dfM.loc[:,~dfM.columns.duplicated()]
totRows=len(dfM.index)
totCols=len(dfM.columns)

# Split sheets if more than 100K
rows_per_sheet=100000
number_of_sheets=math.ceil(totRows/rows_per_sheet)
start_index=0
end_index=rows_per_sheet

workbook = pyexcelerate.Workbook() # Creating new workbook

for sheet_num in range(number_of_sheets):
    df=dfM.iloc[start_index:end_index] # Splitting based on index
    sheet_nme=sheet + '_' + str(sheet_num+1) # Adding the sheet number to the sheet name
    numRows=len(df.index)
    
    # Preparing excel data
    excel = [df.columns] + list(df.values)

    worksheet=workbook.new_sheet(sheet_nme,data=excel) # Creating new sheet

    # df_format --> ['C_Header',P_Color','P_Color_Val','P_Format']
    df_format=df_format[df_format.C_Header.isin(df.columns.to_list())]
    
    # loop1
    # Start iterating through the columns to apply the format
    for i in range(totCols):
        format_obj=pyexcelerate.Format(df_format.iloc[i,3])
        if df_format.iloc[i,1] == 'E' and df_format.iloc[i,2] > ' ':
            r,g,b=hex_to_rgb(df_format.iloc[i,2])
            fill_obj=pyexcelerate.Fill(background=pyexcelerate.Color(r,g,b))
            worksheet.set_col_style(i+1,pyexcelerate.Style(fill=fill_obj,format=format_obj))
        else :
            worksheet.set_col_style(i+1,pyexcelerate.Style(format=format_obj))

    # loop2
    # Start iterating through the columns and the rows to apply the format for header alone
    for i in range(totCols):
        font_obj=pyexcelerate.Font(bold=True)
        if df_format.iloc[i,2] > ' ': #Excel cell starts from (1,1) and dataframe from (0,0)
            r,g,b=hex_to_rgb(df_format.iloc[i,2])
            fill_obj=pyexcelerate.Fill(background=pyexcelerate.Color(r,g,b))
            worksheet.set_cell_style(1,i+1,pyexcelerate.Style(fill=fill_obj,font=font_obj))
        else :
            worksheet.set_cell_style(1,i+1,pyexcelerate.Style(font=font_obj))
            
    #loop3
    # This is for higlighting the summary row if any
    if total_row : # if there is a summary row
        for i in range(totCols):
            format_obj=pyexcelerate.Format(df_format.iloc[i,3])
            font_obj=pyexcelerate.Font(bold=True,color=pyexcelerate.Color(255,0,0))
            fill_obj=pyexcelerate.Fill(background=pyexcelerate.Color(255,255,0))
            worksheet.set_cell_style(numRows+1,i+1,pyexcelerate.Style(fill=fill_obj,format=format_obj,font=font_obj))
    
    start_index=end_index
    end_index=end_index + rows_per_sheet
    df='' # clearing memory
            
workbook.save(excel_file) # Saving the file
```

At the time of this save instruction , it gives the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyexcelerate/Writer.py", line 82, in save
    f.write(s.encode("utf-8"))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1043, in close
    raise RuntimeError('File size unexpectedly exceeded ZIP64 '
RuntimeError: File size unexpectedly exceeded ZIP64 limit"
```

I tried using a byteIO as well. But no luck.

```
from io import BytesIO

buff = BytesIO() # BytesIO is used to avoid zip archive writing error for large files
wb.save(buff) # Saving the file to bytesio memory
with open(excel_file,"wb") as f:
f.write(xlsx_file.getvalue())
```

It doens't matter whether saving to a disk or memory, it gives the error.
Below is the full error message. (FYI-I use redis rq for task serialization)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyexcelerate/Writer.py", line 82, in save
    f.write(s.encode("utf-8"))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1043, in close
    raise RuntimeError('File size unexpectedly exceeded ZIP64 '
RuntimeError: File size unexpectedly exceeded ZIP64 limit

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 1061, in perform_job
    rv = job.perform()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 821, in perform
    self._result = self._execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 844, in _execute
    result = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "./app.py", line 763, in fulfillRequest
    wb.save(xlsx_file) # Saving the file to bytesio memory
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyexcelerate/Workbook.py", line 105, in save
    self._save(filename_or_filehandle)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyexcelerate/Workbook.py", line 97, in _save
    self._writer.save(file_handle)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyexcelerate/Writer.py", line 89, in save
    zf.write(tfn, "xl/worksheets/sheet%s.xml" % (index))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1614, in write
    "Can't write to ZIP archive while an open writing handle exists"
ValueError: Can't write to ZIP archive while an open writing handle exists
```

As per Jan' suggestion I tried listing the length of len(s.encode("utf-8"))
And it looks to have more than 3 GB.
Is there a way I can reduce this size ? This file is failing with the file limit issue.   Or any way out ?

```
Dataframe shape: (163165, 305) 
Dataframe size : 3.4339 GB

sheet=1 : Number of sheetStream=26117755 : Total length=2687100303
sheet=2 : Number of sheetStream=844      : Total length=43625
sheet=3 : Number of sheetStream=328447   : Total length=31528899
sheet=4 : Number of sheetStream=12172832 : Total length=997473023
         
            Number of sheet = 4  
Total Number of sheetStream = 38619878  
         Grand Total length = 3716145850 (3.4609 GB)
```

One more thing to mention is that even though the size in the memory is so huge, when it writes as an xlsx into disk, the size is significantly less.
for example, the below case successfully runs and created a 125 MB xlsx file.

```
Dataframe shape: (116123, 305) 
Dataframe size : 2.4296 GB

sheet=1 : Number of sheetStream=17904832 : Total length=1840807057
sheet=2 :      Number of sheetStream=844 : Total length=43625
sheet=3 :   Number of sheetStream=314923 : Total length=30162834
sheet=4 :  Number of sheetStream=9091957 : Total length=744388260

            Number of sheet = 4 
Total Number of sheetStream = 27312556 
         Grand Total length = 2615401776 (2.4357 GB)
```

So, point is, even though it is considering it as a huge file, as xlsx on the disk, its a small file.

As per charlie's suggestion, I tried again with openpyxl, but its awfully slow. And failed with serialization error(lxml.etree._raiseSerialisationError\nlxml.etree.SerialisationError: IO_WRITE) after 43% of processing. (Means before even saving the workbook)

Here is the code I tried...

```
    # Remove dup columns from dataframe if any.
    dfM=dfM.loc[:,~dfM.columns.duplicated()]
    totRows=len(dfM.index)
    totCols=len(dfM.columns)

    # Split sheets if more than 100K
    rows_per_sheet=100000
    number_of_sheets=math.ceil(totRows/rows_per_sheet)
    if number_of_sheets == 0 : number_of_sheets = 1 # Atleast one sheet should be written even if empty.
    start_index=0
    end_index=rows_per_sheet

    assert LXML is True
    wb = Workbook(write_only=True) #Creating openpyxl workbook
       
    for sheet_num in range(number_of_sheets):
        df=dfM.iloc[start_index:end_index] # Splitting based on index
        sheet_nme=sheet + '_' + str(sheet_num+1) # Adding the sheet number to the sheet name
        num_rows=len(df.index)
        
        worksheet = wb.create_sheet(sheet_nme)

        # df_format --> ['C_Header',P_Color','P_Color_Val','P_Format']
        df_format=df_format[df_format.C_Header.isin(df.columns.to_list())]
        
        # Writing dataframe to excel row by row
        row_num=-1 # To start indexing from zero
        for row in dataframe_to_rows(df,index=False,header=True):
            row_num+=1
            col_num=-1 # To start indexing from zero
            styled_row=[]
            # Styling cell by cell
            for cell in row :
                col_num+=1
                cell = WriteOnlyCell(worksheet,value=cell)
                if row_num == 0: # Logic only for head row
                    cell.font=Font(bold=True)
                    if df_format.iloc[col_num,2] > ' ': #coloring for header
                        colorFill=PatternFill(start_color=df_format.iloc[col_num,2],end_color=df_format.iloc[col_num,2],fill_type='solid')
                        cell.fill=colorFill
                if row_num > 0 : # Logic for other rows
                    if df_format.iloc[col_num,1] == 'E' :
                        cell.number_format=df_format.iloc[col_num,3] # Formatting for the cells
                        if df_format.iloc[col_num,2] > ' ': #coloring for other cells
                            colorFill=PatternFill(start_color=df_format.iloc[col_num,2],end_color=df_format.iloc[col_num,2],fill_type='solid')
                            cell.fill=colorFill
                if total_row and row_num == num_rows : # Logic for summary row
                    cell.number_format=df_format.iloc[col_num,3]
                    cell.font=Font(bold=True,color='FF0000') 
                    colorFill=PatternFill(start_color='FFFF00',end_color='FFFF00',fill_type='solid')
                    cell.fill=colorFill          
                styled_row.append(cell)
            worksheet.append(styled_row)
          
        start_index=end_index
        end_index=end_index + rows_per_sheet
        df='' # clearing memory
    
    # Cleaning df those are no loner needed
    dfM='' # clearing memory
    df_format='' # clearing memory
    #Finally writing the workbook
    buff = BytesIO() # BytesIO is used to avoid zip archive writing error for large files
    
    wb.save(buff) # Saving the file to bytesio memory
    wb.close()
    
    with open(excel_file,"wb") as f:
        f.write(buff.getvalue())
```

Any other suggestions ?

Comment: have you checked `len(s.encode("utf-8"))`?

Comment: Considering all the manipulation of the data frame you're doing, I wouldn't worry about the __alleged__ performance of this library over that. As soon as you start adding formatting in Excel, they all get slow.

Comment: @JanWilamowski : I have added the stats in the question.

Comment: @CharlieClark : Performance is fine now. I see even this 3GB one getting processed in less than 10 mins before the save instruction. My current concern is this size limit.

Comment: You're note about file size is irrelevant: it's precisely the compression that's causing problems. Speed sounds reasonable but I'd expect similar with openpyxl and xlsxwriter in optimsed modes as there are only so many ways you can write XML. The memory problem looks like something in the library you're using. What is the size of the dataframe in rows and columns?

Comment: @CharlieClark : Dataframe shape: (163165, 305) 
Dataframe size : 3.4339 GB

Answer (score 1):

For comparison I mocked this in openpyxl, though I didn't bother with the formatting.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import process_time
from openpyxl import LXML
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

assert LXML is True

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(200000, size=(163165, 305)))

start = process_time()

wb = Workbook(write_only=True)
ws = wb.create_sheet()

for row in dataframe_to_rows(df,  index=True, header=True):
    ws.append(row)
    
wb.save("big_df.xsx")

stop = process_time()

print(f"Took {stop - start:.2f}s")
```

Took 358.46s

Comment: No luck with formatting and coloring. It failed after 3 Hrs of processing with this error. " in lxml.etree._raiseSerialisationError\nlxml.etree.SerialisationError: IO_WRITE "

Comment: You're obviously not using this code but that is a memory error.

Comment: Yes I used this code. I have updated the complete code in question, if u do not believe me :-) . When I use pyexcelerate, I do not get any memory error but the zip file limit error only.

Comment: So, you're still bouncing around in the dataframe? This is bound to be slow. You must adapt your code to use the openpyxl approach. And it does look like you are reaching certain general or file size memory limits.

Comment: dataframe is used only as the source of data.

Comment: `df_format.iloc[col_num,2]` is going to be slow and it seems you do it a lot. How fast are things without any formatting?